# Regex detect newline

Tags: regex

I was trying to match regex with a text but it's hard to find the exact match.
Here is the test text

```
SimulationControl,
      \unique-object
      \memo Note that the following 3 fields are related to the Sizing:Zone, Sizing:System,
      \memo and Sizing:Plant objects.  Having these fields set to Yes but no corresponding
      \memo Sizing object will not cause the sizing to be done. However, having any of these
      \memo fields set to No, the corresponding Sizing object is ignored.
      \memo Note also, if you want to do system sizing, you must also do zone sizing in the same
      \memo run or an error will result.
  A1, \field Do Zone Sizing Calculation
      \note If Yes, Zone sizing is accomplished from corresponding Sizing:Zone objects
      \note and autosize fields.
      \type choice
      \key Yes
      \key No
      \default No
  A2, \field Do System Sizing Calculation
      \note If Yes, System sizing is accomplished from corresponding Sizing:System objects
      \note and autosize fields.
      \note If Yes, Zone sizing (previous field) must also be Yes.
      \type choice
      \key Yes
      \key No
      \default No

Building,
       \memo Describes parameters that are used during the simulation
       \memo of the building. There are necessary correlations between the entries for
       \memo this object and some entries in the Site:WeatherStation and
       \memo Site:HeightVariation objects, specifically the Terrain field.
```

so what i am trying to do is selecting only text before 'Building' class begins.
this is the regex i am doing that , but i am failing to detect the empty line before 'Building' so i can stop before it, so it selects all the text

```
^[A-Z].*?,(\s*\\.*)*\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s\\:.\(\)\*;]*\n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is select everything up until the first empty line, remember that it is only two consecutive `\n`, right? You can use something like

```
^(?s).*?\n\n
```

`(?s)` is an inline flag, meaning `.` will also match newlines. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bA9uF9) for fun.

---

If you want to match any of these blocks (not just the first one) you can use:

```
(?s).*?(?:\n\n|$)
```

Remove the anchor, `(?:...)` is a non capturing group and `\n\n|$` will catch an empty line or the end of the document.

**Edit**

You can use `\n\s*\n` if you're worried there might be trailing whitespaces on the empty line, compliments from @SebastianH

Comment: that was what i am looking for, but i have another question , the document is composed of several blocks like that one, so what can i do to select a block in the middle of the document for example, thank you

Comment: @Helmi: On what criteria? Please try to provide these additional question in the original question next time, it's clearer for everyone. I edited answer.

Comment: In many situations you cannot be sure that the "empty line" is completly devoid of whitespace (blanks, tabs). Then it might be good to use a pattern like `\n\s*\n` instead of `\n\n`. `\s` matches any whitespace character.